# User creation remote logging

Tags: log, logging, syslog, adduser, rsyslog

I am trying to centralize logs from different server to one server.

I can centralize logging information via adding `auth.* @server_ip:port` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` from the clients, but now I don't retrieve user creation logging information. However, these logs are in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Example :

```
Jun  1 09:46:20 host sshd[12867]: Accepted password for adminelk from 10.0.0.2 port 63676 ssh2
Jun  1 09:46:20 host sshd[12867]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user adminelk by (uid=0)
Jun  1 09:46:26 host su[12879]: Successful su for root by adminelk
Jun  1 09:46:26 host su[12879]: + /dev/pts/0 adminelk:root
Jun  1 09:46:26 host su[12879]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by adminelk(uid=1000)
Jun  1 10:17:01 host CRON[12951]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun  1 10:17:01 host CRON[12951]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun  1 10:17:01 host groupadd[12955]: group added to /etc/group: name=johnny, GID=1002
Jun  1 10:17:01 host groupadd[12955]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=johnny
Jun  1 10:17:01 host groupadd[12955]: new group: name=johnny, GID=1002
Jun  1 10:17:01 host useradd[12959]: new user: name=johnny, UID=1004, GID=1002, home=/home/johnny, shell=/bin/bash
Jun  1 10:17:05 host passwd[12966]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for johnny
Jun  1 10:17:08 host chfn[12967]: changed user 'johnny' information
```

I can retrieve sshd logs but not useradd logs...

How could I retrieve these logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use `auth,authpriv.*     @server_ip:port`

### Details

You are using the wrong facility resp. not all correct facilities.

To analyze the behaviour I run

```
journalctl -o verbose -t useradd -t groupadd -t passwd -f
```

in one window and did

```
adduser foo
```

in another (both as `root`).

`journald` intercepts (local) syslog messages that can be viewed with `journalctl`. The latter allows for various output formats, one of which is *verbose with all syslog message fields*.

The output then was something like:

```
Wed 2018-06-06 21:05:22.618392 CEST  [...]
    ...
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    ...
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=groupadd
    ...
    MESSAGE=group added to /etc/group: name=foo, GID=1004
Wed 2018-06-06 21:05:22.630643 CEST [...]
    ...
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    ...
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=groupadd
    ...
    MESSAGE=group added to /etc/gshadow: name=foo
    ...
Wed 2018-06-06 21:05:22.631667 CEST [...]
    ...
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    ...
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=groupadd
    ...
    MESSAGE=new group: name=foo, GID=1004
    ...
Wed 2018-06-06 21:05:22.635070 CEST [...]
    ...
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    ...
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=useradd
    ...
    MESSAGE=new user: name=foo, UID=1002, GID=1004, home=/home/foo, shell=/bin/bash
    ...
Wed 2018-06-06 21:05:22.699151 CEST [...]
    PRIORITY=4
    ...
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    ...
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=passwd
    MESSAGE=pam_ecryptfs: PAM passphrase change module retrieved a NULL passphrase; nothing to do
    ...
```

As we can see here, the `SYSLOG_FACILITY` is `10` for all those messages. [This is not `auth` but `authpriv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Facility).

In fact, my rsyslog configuration contains the line

```
auth,authpriv.* /var/log/auth.log
```

in the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.

So my suggestion is to use

```
auth,authpriv.*     @server_ip:port
```

to not only forward `auth` messages but also `authpriv` messages.